# Add columns of standardised residuals from different models using the same IVs but different DVs

Tags: r, linear-regression, tidyverse

I would like a Tidyverse approach to solving the following problem...

I am using the diamonds dataset (from ggplot2) as an example.

```
structure(list(carat = c(0.23, 0.21, 0.23, 0.29, 0.31), cut = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Premium", 
"Ideal"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), color = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), clarity = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("I1", "SI2", "SI1", "VS2", "VS1", 
"VVS2", "VVS1", "IF"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), depth = c(61.5, 
59.8, 56.9, 62.4, 63.3), table = c(55, 61, 65, 58, 58), price = c(326L, 
326L, 327L, 334L, 335L), x = c(3.95, 3.89, 4.05, 4.2, 4.34), 
    y = c(3.98, 3.84, 4.07, 4.23, 4.35), z = c(2.43, 2.31, 2.31, 
    2.63, 2.75)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to run 3 separate linear regressions where the DV is different but the IVs stay the same, for example:

- x ~ depth + price
- y ~ depth + price
- z ~ depth + price

And I would like to add a new column to the original dataframe that includes the standard residuals from each model for every observation (i.e. x_stdresiduals, y_stdresiduals, z_stdresiduals).

Comment: Please define DV and IV

Comment: DV, in this case, would be x, y and z. IVs would be depth and price (predictors).

Comment: Ok, add sample data with `dput(head(df,n))`. Choose n that allows for minimal reproducibility.

Comment: @NelsonGon - done.

Comment: Oh, you need one data frame returned?

Comment: @NelsonGon - Yep.

Answer (score 2):

One brute-force approach would be

```
diamonds %>% 
  mutate(
    x_stdresiduals = lm(x ~ depth + price)$residuals,
    y_stdresiduals = lm(y ~ depth + price)$residuals,
    z_stdresiduals = lm(z ~ depth + price)$residuals
  )
```

Comment: This is useful, but I don't think it works in my case because I have missing values. So I get the error "must be size X or 1, not Y".